# Iterator on nth element of each vector in vector<vector<T>>

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

Let's say I have some vector of vectors of type `T` i.e. `vector<vector<T>> vec`.

Now, I want to perform some STL algorithm over the nth element of each of the nested vectors. For example, I want to sort only the nth element of each vector, leaving all of the other elements untouched.

To do this, I need some sort of iterator such that it will iterate over the nested vectors, but dereferencing the iterator will yield the nth element of the vector. Is this a reasonable approach and if so, is there any existing implementation? Preferably in the STL.

**Motivation:** I need to perform some STL algorithm on nested vectors but cannot use any extra space.

**Example:** Let `Adaptor<N>(It iterator)` be our desired iterator class that is an iterator to the element at position N in the nested array, and calling `next` on the returned iterator would take us to the element at position `N` in the next nested array.

```
vector<vector<int>> vec {{1,3,2}, {4,1,10}, {3,3,3}, {9,8,7}}
sort(Adaptor<2>(vec.begin()), Adaptor<2>(vec.end()));
```

would yield `vec`

```
{{1,3,2}, {4,1,3}, {3,3,7}, {9,8,10}}
```

Comment: 1) No, it is not a reasonable approach, 2) moot point, there is no existing implementation. That seems to answer what you asked.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation why it is unreasonable?

Comment: Because C++ iterators simply don't work this way. Dereferencing an iterator yields the value the iterator references, not some other completely unrelated value.

Comment: Sure, but can you not create your own iterator class that provides an override for dereferencing? The value isn’t completely unrelated. In fact it will always just be n positions in front of the base iterator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what's unreasonable? there are plenty of iterator adaptors (though [few](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) [in](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) the standard library)

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a position to use Boost, [`boost::iterator_adaptor`](https://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/generic/adaptor.html) makes this reasonably easy to implement:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55007135c1e4526b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::size_t N,typename Iterator>
class nth_iterator:
  public boost::iterator_adaptor<
    nth_iterator<N,Iterator>,Iterator,
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype((*std::declval<Iterator>())[N])>
  >
{
public:
  nth_iterator()=default;
  nth_iterator(const Iterator& it):nth_iterator::iterator_adaptor_{it}{}
  nth_iterator(const nth_iterator&)=default;
  nth_iterator& operator=(const nth_iterator&)=default;

private:
  friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

  decltype(auto) dereference()const
  {
    return (*this->base_reference())[N];
  }
};

template<std::size_t N,typename Iterator>
auto nth(Iterator it)
{
  return nth_iterator<N,Iterator>(it);
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec{{1,3,2}, {4,1,10}, {3,3,3}, {9,8,7}};

  auto print_vec=[&]{
    std::cout<<"{";
    const char* delim1="";
    for(auto&& x:vec){
      std::cout<<delim1<<"{";
      delim1=", ";
      const char* delim2="";
      for(auto&& y:x){
        std::cout<<delim2<<y;
        delim2=",";
      }
      std::cout<<"}";
    }
    std::cout<<"}\n";
  };

  print_vec();
  std::sort(nth<2>(vec.begin()),nth<2>(vec.end()));
  print_vec();  
}
```

**Output**

```
{{1,3,2}, {4,1,10}, {3,3,3}, {9,8,7}}
{{1,3,2}, {4,1,3}, {3,3,7}, {9,8,10}}
```